# Access to wordpress multisite not available

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have an issue with a Wordpress multisite. The sites main site was "moved" and the DNS does not point to this server anymore.

Now I cant access the network admin area anymore.
I tried to change several settings, but that lead to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT issues and problems on the current still available subsites url handling (images weren't shown anymore)

Current main site where DNS is not pointing to the server anymore: blog id 1.
Site id which should be the new main site -> blog id 3

I changed the following:
wp-config.php

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.oldsite.at'); ->  define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.newsite.at');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); -> stays the same according to blogs table
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); -> define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 3);
```

This did not solve the problem, when accessing the network area, the [www.oldsite.at](http://www.oldsite.at) was still opened which is not a multisite anymore and images weren't shown anymore on [www.newsite.at](http://www.newsite.at) (404 errors in the console)

Next steps:
In the wp_site table I changed the domain from [www.oldsite.at](http://www.oldsite.at) to [www.newsite.at](http://www.newsite.at)
in the wp_sitemeta I changed the siteurl from [www.oldsite.at](http://www.oldsite.at) to [www.newsite.at](http://www.newsite.at)

-> nothing changed.

So now I'm out of options, because I cannot find anymore settings which are not related to other subsites for the multisite.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?